# Take unique values from certain columns and add them to an existing column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame (meat  = c("lamb, beef", "chicken, pork, beef", "venison, beef, lamb", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                  fish = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "sardines, tuna, snapper", "snapper", "kingfish, sardines", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                  veges = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "onions, potatoes, leeks", "celery, leeks", "carrots, onions, potatoes", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                  food = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "chicken, lamb, beef", "sardines, kingfish, tuna", "potatoes, leeks")
                  )

                  meat                    fish                     veges                     food
1           lamb, beef                      NA                        NA                       NA
2  chicken, pork, beef                      NA                        NA                       NA
3  venison, beef, lamb                      NA                        NA                       NA
4                   NA sardines, tuna, snapper                        NA                       NA
5                   NA                 snapper                        NA                       NA
6                   NA      kingfish, sardines                        NA                       NA
7                   NA                      NA   onions, potatoes, leeks                       NA
8                   NA                      NA             celery, leeks                       NA
9                   NA                      NA carrots, onions, potatoes                       NA
10                  NA                      NA                        NA      chicken, lamb, beef
11                  NA                      NA                        NA sardines, kingfish, tuna
12                  NA                      NA                        NA          potatoes, leeks
```

Lets say the above food data used to be collected by stating which items were present based on their category (meat, fish, veges) but now the data is collected inside a single food column. How do I get unique values inside the meat/fish/veges columns and add them to the food column (like the bottom three rows)?

There are multiple values separated by commas inside the meat/fish/veges columns, so will I first need to extract these?

I've spent a lot of time searching for an answer on here but I can't find a scenario that roughly matches what I'm wanting. I've played around with coalesce() and distinct(), but it doesn't look like they can be used in the way I'm wanting. It's difficult to articulate the problem in a way that will return relevant packages.

**Edit:** I apologise for screwing up the reprex - the NAs are actual NAs in the data. I also realised the reprex is not right. This is the example data and what I'm trying to get to happen. I want to move/copy the values from the 'cat_' columns to a 'new' column as below. Multiple text strings are separated by a comma:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  cat_1 = c("A,B", "C", "D,E,F", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  cat_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "B,D", "G", "A", NA, NA, NA),
  cat_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A,D", "B", "J,L"),
  new = c("A,B", "C", "D,E,F", "B,D", "G", "A", "A,D", "B", "J,L")
)

  cat_1 cat_2 cat_3   new
1   A,B  <NA>  <NA>   A,B
2     C  <NA>  <NA>     C
3 D,E,F  <NA>  <NA> D,E,F
4  <NA>   B,D  <NA>   B,D
5  <NA>     G  <NA>     G
6  <NA>     A  <NA>     A
7  <NA>  <NA>   A,D   A,D
8  <NA>  <NA>     B     B
9  <NA>  <NA>   J,L   J,L
```

Comment: could you please post the expected table

Comment: In your example, the bottom set of rows in the `meat` section is missing **venison** and **pork**.  Likewise **snapper** for `fish`, and many are missing under `veges`.  Is that intentional?  It's not clear what your expected answer is, as @jkatam said.

Comment: as wackojacko1997 said OP, NA != "NA"

Comment: `mutate(dat, food = coalesce(!!!\`is.na<-\`(dat, dat == 'NA')))`

Comment: `coalesce(!!!type_convert(dat))`

Comment: I really screwed up the reprex and I apologise for wasting your time. I've edited the OP with the reprex I should have used originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, you need to convert `"NA"` (which is a character) to a real `NA` (looks the same but isn't).  In your `data.frame()` call, you're making them as text.  Here's a quick way to correct that:

```
dat[dat=="NA"] <- NA
> dat
                  meat                    fish                     veges                     food
1           lamb, beef                    <NA>                      <NA>                     <NA>
2  chicken, pork, beef                    <NA>                      <NA>                     <NA>
3  venison, beef, lamb                    <NA>                      <NA>                     <NA>
4                 <NA> sardines, tuna, snapper                      <NA>                     <NA>
5                 <NA>                 snapper                      <NA>                     <NA>
6                 <NA>      kingfish, sardines                      <NA>                     <NA>
7                 <NA>                    <NA>   onions, potatoes, leeks                     <NA>
8                 <NA>                    <NA>             celery, leeks                     <NA>
9                 <NA>                    <NA> carrots, onions, potatoes                     <NA>
10                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>      chicken, lamb, beef
11                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA> sardines, kingfish, tuna
12                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>          potatoes, leeks
```

Now you can use the splice operator (`!!!`) with a vector setting the preferred order of columns that you want to `coalesce()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

vec <- c("food", "veges", "fish", "meat")

dat %>%
  mutate(food = coalesce(!!!select(.,all_of(vec))))
```

Output:

```
> dat %>%
+   mutate(food = coalesce(!!!select(.,all_of(vec))))
# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Rowwise: 
   meat                fish                    veges                     food                     
   <chr>               <chr>                   <chr>                     <chr>                    
 1 lamb, beef          NA                      NA                        lamb, beef               
 2 chicken, pork, beef NA                      NA                        chicken, pork, beef      
 3 venison, beef, lamb NA                      NA                        venison, beef, lamb      
 4 NA                  sardines, tuna, snapper NA                        sardines, tuna, snapper  
 5 NA                  snapper                 NA                        snapper                  
 6 NA                  kingfish, sardines      NA                        kingfish, sardines       
 7 NA                  NA                      onions, potatoes, leeks   onions, potatoes, leeks  
 8 NA                  NA                      celery, leeks             celery, leeks            
 9 NA                  NA                      carrots, onions, potatoes carrots, onions, potatoes
10 NA                  NA                      NA                        chicken, lamb, beef      
11 NA                  NA                      NA                        sardines, kingfish, tuna 
12 NA                  NA                      NA                        potatoes, leeks
```

## EDIT ADDED:

Okay, so you want to add the coalesced data as a new column. Same as above, but mutate a new column (`new_col`):

```
> dat %>%
+   mutate(new_col = coalesce(!!!select(.,all_of(vec))))  #  <-- see edit here
# A tibble: 12 × 5
# Rowwise: 
   meat                fish                    veges                     food                     new_col                  
   <chr>               <chr>                   <chr>                     <chr>                    <chr>                    
 1 lamb, beef          NA                      NA                        NA                       lamb, beef               
 2 chicken, pork, beef NA                      NA                        NA                       chicken, pork, beef      
 3 venison, beef, lamb NA                      NA                        NA                       venison, beef, lamb      
 4 NA                  sardines, tuna, snapper NA                        NA                       sardines, tuna, snapper  
 5 NA                  snapper                 NA                        NA                       snapper                  
 6 NA                  kingfish, sardines      NA                        NA                       kingfish, sardines       
 7 NA                  NA                      onions, potatoes, leeks   NA                       onions, potatoes, leeks  
 8 NA                  NA                      celery, leeks             NA                       celery, leeks            
 9 NA                  NA                      carrots, onions, potatoes NA                       carrots, onions, potatoes
10 NA                  NA                      NA                        chicken, lamb, beef      chicken, lamb, beef      
11 NA                  NA                      NA                        sardines, kingfish, tuna sardines, kingfish, tuna 
12 NA                  NA                      NA                        potatoes, leeks          potatoes, leeks
```

Comment: What do you mean?  Reassign the column?  I did that with `food` up above, and here I just created `new_col` after reading your edit.  After playing around with this more, I think you could do this just fine without the splice-operator, too.  I was stealing code from a similar problem I had a year ago when I answered, and I probably over-complicated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant is it not possible to use assignment to 'move' the values from meat/fish/veges to a blank column in the data? I've tried this with my own data and it works fine with a single column but when I try to do it with multiple columns I gte an error about the assigned data having double the rows of the existing data (when trying to reassign two columns). Is it not possible to reassign the data from multiple columns into a new column so that NAs get overwritten?

Comment: What you're describing in words reads to me exactly like what I think I'm showing in my EDIT ADDED above.  I think you need to post the code you're trying out along with the error you're getting.  You have to scroll in the window above, but isn't the `new_col` showing what you want?  I don't understand how my answer differs from what you describe at the end of your edit in the OP.

Comment: Its OK I found a simpler solution that was easier for me to understand elsewhere. If we pretend dat$food is an existing blank column:

dat$food <- coalesce(dat$meat, dat$fish, dat$veges, dat$food)

I realise I really screwed up the reprex and mucked everyone round so I apologise for that.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear at this stage what precisely you want, but here are a couple of possibilities

```
# Assuming you want (for example) 'chicken, lamb, beef' to be one row  
dat %>%
    select(important) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    unique() %>%
    {tibble(food = .)} %>%
    add_row(.data = dat)

# Assuming you want 'chicken, lamb, beef' to be three rows 
dat %>%
    select(important) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    unique() %>%
    str_split(", ") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    unique() %>%
    {tibble(food = .)} %>%
    add_row(.data = dat)
```

Output of option #2:

```
                  meat                    fish                     veges
1           lamb, beef                      NA                        NA
2  chicken, pork, beef                      NA                        NA
3  venison, beef, lamb                      NA                        NA
4                   NA sardines, tuna, snapper                        NA
5                   NA                 snapper                        NA
6                   NA      kingfish, sardines                        NA
7                   NA                      NA   onions, potatoes, leeks
8                   NA                      NA             celery, leeks
9                   NA                      NA carrots, onions, potatoes
10                  NA                      NA                        NA
11                  NA                      NA                        NA
12                  NA                      NA                        NA
13                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
14                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
15                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
16                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
17                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
18                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
19                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
20                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
21                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
22                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
23                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
24                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
25                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
26                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
27                <NA>                    <NA>                      <NA>
                       food
1                        NA
2                        NA
3                        NA
4                        NA
5                        NA
6                        NA
7                        NA
8                        NA
9                        NA
10      chicken, lamb, beef
11 sardines, kingfish, tuna
12          potatoes, leeks
13                     lamb
14                     beef
15                  chicken
16                     pork
17                  venison
18                       NA
19                 sardines
20                     tuna
21                  snapper
22                 kingfish
23                   onions
24                 potatoes
25                    leeks
26                   celery
27                  carrots
```

Another way (credit to wackojacko for spotting the NA problem before I did)

```
dat[dat == "NA"] <- NA
dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(meat) | !is.na(fish) | !is.na(veges)) %>%
  select(-food) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "food_type", values_to = "food", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(food = str_split(food, ", ")) %>%
  unnest_longer(food)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 22 × 2
   food_type food    
   <chr>     <chr>   
 1 meat      lamb    
 2 meat      beef    
 3 meat      chicken 
 4 meat      pork    
 5 meat      beef    
 6 meat      venison 
 7 meat      beef    
 8 meat      lamb    
 9 fish      sardines
10 fish      tuna    
# ℹ 12 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please try the below code without the use of `coalesce`

```r
new <- dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., "NA")),
                                    food=na.omit(c_across(everything())))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Rowwise: 
   meat                fish                    veges               food 
   <chr>               <chr>                   <chr>               <chr>
 1 lamb, beef          <NA>                    <NA>                lamb…
 2 chicken, pork, beef <NA>                    <NA>                chic…
 3 venison, beef, lamb <NA>                    <NA>                veni…
 4 <NA>                sardines, tuna, snapper <NA>                sard…
 5 <NA>                snapper                 <NA>                snap…
 6 <NA>                kingfish, sardines      <NA>                king…
 7 <NA>                <NA>                    onions, potatoes, … onio…
 8 <NA>                <NA>                    celery, leeks       cele…
 9 <NA>                <NA>                    carrots, onions, p… carr…
10 <NA>                <NA>                    <NA>                chic…
11 <NA>                <NA>                    <NA>                sard…
12 <NA>                <NA>                    <NA>                pota…
```